# How to compare multiple files based on only file type and size

Tags: c

The goal is to compare files by size and filter those of the same size. 
For that you need to compare every file to every file. 
However the first loop doesnt work so the search of the first directory is stuck at the first file.

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char *v[]) {
    struct dirent *d_verzeichnis1;
    struct dirent *d_verzeichnis2;
    DIR *dir1;
    DIR *dir2;
    FILE *file = fopen(v[3], "W");
    dir1 = opendir(v[1]);
    dir2 = opendir(v[2]);
    struct stat filesize1;
    struct stat filesize2;

    while ((d_verzeichnis1 = readdir(dir1)) != NULL) {
        stat((d_verzeichnis1->d_name), &filesize1);
        while ((d_verzeichnis2 = readdir(dir2)) != NULL) {
            stat((d_verzeichnis2->d_name), &filesize2);
            if (filesize1.st_size == filesize2.st_size);
            {
                printf("%s und %s sind gleich\n", 
                       d_verzeichnis1->d_name, d_verzeichnis2->d_name);
            }
        }   
        d_verzeichnis1 = readdir(dir1); 
    }
}
```

Comment: you're not comparing all files from `dir1` against all files from `dir2`, you'll need to use 2 loops to do that. What you have now reads the first file from each directory, compares them, then the next file from each directory, compares them, etc.. until you run out of files in one of the directories (or an error occurs). You need to compare the first file from `dir1` against _all_ the files in `dir2`, then the 2nd file from `dir1` against _all_ the files in `dir2`, etc.

Comment: This may be <O/T> depending on your task, but if you're really looking for duplicates, you should hash the file contents and compare the hashes. Obviously, two files can be the same size, have the same name and extension, yet have different content.

Comment: If this is an exercise, then as @yano has mentioned, you'll need to loop through the files and compare them .. alternatively, you could use `fdupes` like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71178/27770) answer suggests.

Comment: For one directory, build a list.. or rather a hash table of the attributes, then scan the other and see if the entry is in this list

Comment: I added the necessary while-loops. However some files arent compared randomly and some files show 0 bytes size wich are obviously not 0 bytes...  Hashing is not allowed as our teacher wants us to work with directories

Comment: Rather than repeatedly iterating over the files in either directory, why not create a struct with the filename and filesize and then fill an array of struct from each directory and then your comparisons would simply be in-memory operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you should verify the actual number of arguments provided on the command line to avoid undefined behavior if fewer than 3 were provided.
- `fopen(v[3], "W");` uses an invalid mode string, you should use `"w"`. It is unclear what this stream pointer is used for anyway.
- `dir1` and `dir2` are not tested: you have undefined behavior if `opendir()` fails.
- `stat` is called with the directory entry name, which is not a relative pathname to the file if the directory is different from the current directory. You should construct the path name from the directory name and entry name.
- `if (filesize1.st_size == filesize2.st_size);` has an extra `;` at the end of the line, causing the following block to execute unconditionally. You should use `K&R style with`{` at the end of the line to avoid such silly mistakes.
- the logic of parallel scan is incorrect: you should reopen or at least rewind the second directory for each entry in the first to allow a full scan for potential matches.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

char *buildpath(char *dest, size_t size, const char *dir, const char *name) {
    size_t len = strlen(dir);
    const char *sep = "";

    if (len > 0 && dir[len - 1] != '/')
        sep = "/";

    if ((unsigned)snprintf(dest, size, "%s%s%s", dir, sep, name) < size)
        return dest;
    else
        return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char path1[1024];
    char path2[1024];
    struct dirent *dp1;
    struct dirent *dp2;
    DIR *dir1;
    DIR *dir2;
    struct stat filesize1;
    struct stat filesize2;

    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "missing argument\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: cmpdir dir1 dir2\n");
        return 1;
    }

    dir1 = opendir(argv[1]);
    if (dir1 == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannt open directory %s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    dir2 = opendir(argv[2]);
    if (dir2 == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannt open directory %s: %s\n", argv[2], strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    while ((dp1 = readdir(dir1)) != NULL) {
        /* ignore . and .. entries */
        if (!strcmp(dp1->d_name, ".")
        ||  !strcmp(dp1->d_name, ".."))
            continue;
        if (!buildpath(path1, sizeof path1, argv[1], dp1->d_name)) {
            /* path too long */
            continue;
        }
        if (stat(path1, &filesize1)) {
            /* cannot stat entry */
            continue;
        }
        if (!S_ISREG(filesize1.st_mode)) {
            /* not a regular file */
            continue;
        }
        rewinddir(dir2);
        while ((dp2 = readdir(dir2)) != NULL) {
            /* ignore . and .. entries */
            if (!strcmp(dp2->d_name, ".")
            ||  !strcmp(dp2->d_name, ".."))
                continue;
            if (!buildpath(path2, sizeof path2, argv[2], dp2->d_name)) {
                /* path too long */
                continue;
            }
            if (stat(path2, &filesize2)) {
                /* cannot stat entry */
                continue;
            }
            if (!S_ISREG(filesize2.st_mode)) {
                /* not a regular file */
                continue;
            }
            if (filesize1.st_size == filesize2.st_size) {
                printf("%s and %s have the same size %llu\n",
                       path1, path2, (unsigned long long)filesize1.st_size);
                /* perform actual comparison... */
            }
        }
    }
    closedir(dir1);
    closedir(dir2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I dont understand your 4th poit: Could you providea code snippet please? I am reopening the second entry in the inner while loop.

Comment: @PaulWolff:  There is an extra `;` in `if (filesize1.st_size == filesize2.st_size); {
                printf("%s und %s sind gleich\n", 
                       d_verzeichnis1->d_name, d_verzeichnis2->d_name);
            }`. This `;` is an empty statement, making the `if` useless.

Comment: The code is very helpful thanks! However I dont understand those parts : char *buildpath(char *dest, size_t size, const char *dir, const char *name) and (!buildpath(path1, sizeof path1, argv[1], dp1->d_name)) and (!buildpath(path2, sizeof path2, argv[2], dp2->d_name)  ?